# Exception org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: mockito wanted but not invoked, Actually there were zero interactions with this mock

Tags: java, junit, mockito

```
  **Test Class**
     @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
        //@WebMvcTest
        @AutoConfigureMockMvc
        @TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:application-test.properties")
        @SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = WebEnvironment.MOCK)
        public class UnitTestingMockitoApplicationTe
 {

  private static @Autowired
Product PRODUCT = new privateProduct(110, static"WXYZ", MockMvc150d, mockMvc;"V20");

    @MockBean
public static final String privateURL ProductRepository= productRepository;"http://localhost:%s/product/";

  //  @Autowired
public static final Integer privatePRODUCT_ID IProductService= productService;101;

    @Test@Autowired
    public voidprivate contextLoads()TestRestTemplate {restTemplate;

    }
@LocalServerPort
    @Test
 private int port;

 public void testProductDelete_02() {
//   1. POST Method doThrow(newCase PersistenceException("ExceptionFrom Occured..!!")).when(productRepository).deleteById(productIdDB);
        verify(productRepository).deleteById(any());@Test
    }
**Service Class**

 @Service
public classvoid IProductServiceImpltestProductSave_01() implementsthrows IProductServiceException {
 
    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository repo;

   ProductDto productDTO = @OverridegivenProductDto();
        publicString voidformat deleteProduct= String.format(IntegerURL+"register", prodIdport) {;
        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new repo.deleteByIdHttpHeaders(prodId);
        }
}
**Controller Class**


 
@RestController
@RequestMappinghttpHeaders.set(""Content-Type", "application/product"json;charset=UTF-8")
public class EmployeeRestController {

    @Autowired;
    private IProductService service;
@DeleteMapping("/delete/{id}")
  HttpEntity<ProductDto> httpEntity public= ResponseEntity<?>new deleteProductHttpEntity<ProductDto>(@PathVariable IntegerproductDTO, idhttpHeaders) {;
        ResponseEntity<?>ResponseEntity<ProductDto> response = null;
        boolean exist = servicerestTemplate.isProductExistexchange(id);
    format, HttpMethod.POST, httpEntity,
  if (exist) {
            serviceProductDto.deleteProduct(idclass);
            assertEquals(response = new ResponseEntity<String>.getStatusCode(id + "-Removed"), HttpStatus.OK);
        } else {
            response = new ResponseEntity<String>assertNotNull("Product NOT FOUND", HttpStatusresponse.BAD_REQUESTgetBody());
        }
        return response;
    }
```

Exception org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: mockito wanted but not invoked, Actually there were zero interactions with this mock OccuringError while extracting response for type [class com.junittesting.dto.ProductDto]
While calling this method from JPA Repository. I am getting mockito wantedm trying to write unit test cases but not invoked. Actually there were zero interactions with this mock at verify call.giving error

Comment: You are not testing any object instances/methods in your test (missing "when" block in terms of "given-when-then", even if `doThrow` was uncommented). What method are you trying to test? Can you show the code of the said method?

Comment: I want to use deleteById() method so how can we use which in Jpa repository and returns void

Comment: Are you using the `deleteById` method in your service class? If so, attach the code showing that. Additionally - what do you want to test here?

Comment: Your test method is empty, aside from calling `verify` on your mock.

Comment: The only thing your test does is to check that `deleteById` got called. It doesn't do anything else first; so it's no surprise that the result is that `deleteById` didn't get called.  You're going to have to add something to your test to make it actually call the method you're trying to test, which presumably is `deleteByProduct` in your `EmployeeRestController` class.

Comment: Your test does not call `deleteByProduct`, so there's no way `deleteById` could have been called.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem could you plz help how to solve then

Comment: @knittl please elaborate i m unable to solve

Comment: @AnkushBanduKamble you are _not_ calling your method. You solve by calling your method.

Comment: @AnkushBanduKamble The solution is that you have to call the method that you're testing.  Methods don't call themselves!  subasri_ has shown you exactly what to do, in their answer.

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem yes got it but i m facing another issue can you elaborate it, i have mentioned above

Comment: So if you have a completely new question, I would suggest you write a completely new question.  You absolutely should NOT change your question after you've got an answer; because it invalidates the work that @subasri_ did to answer your question, and makes a mockery of the whole Stack Overflow model of questions and answers.  Please change this question back to the one that subasri_ answered.

Comment: @subasri_ sorry brother, I have changed it to original one____@DawoodibnKareem Done Changed to orginal one

Comment: Somebody If Possible answer to this question as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74995829/org-hibernate-mappingexception-could-not-locate-collectionpersister-for-role

Answer (score 2):

The invocation of the actual method under test is missing in your `testProductDelete_02` method. So the verification of `deleteById` also doesn't not happen.

If your aim is to test the `deleteProduct` method in the `IProductServiceImpl` class, your test case for the same should modified like below:

```
@Test
public void testProductDelete_02() {
   productService.deleteProduct(new Integer(1));
   verify(productRepository).deleteById(any());
}
```

Only after the actual invocation of the method in the service class is made, execution enters the method and control comes to the line `repo.deleteById(prodId);`. Now the method call is verified and this test method should pass

Comment: I’d suggest you post this as another question so that anyone facing your previous question as issue might find this discussion meaningful and helpful